# Reading/Writing is not working in my TCP code

Tags: c, networking, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

I have a basic TCP client/server program.

I have a method in both the client and the server that reads and writes.  It works perfectly the first time I run it, but when it runs again (it's in a loop) it doesn't read anything in.

```
void printout(int newsockfd, char buffer) {
n = write(newsockfd, a2, 256);
n = write(newsockfd, a3, 256);
n = write(newsockfd, a4, 256);
n = write(newsockfd, a5, 256);
n = write(newsockfd, a6, 256);
}
```

in the server

```
void printout(char buffer[], int sockfd) {
bzero(buffer, 256);
n = read(sockfd, buffer, 256);
printf("%s\n", buffer);
n = read(sockfd, buffer, 256);
printf("%s\n", buffer);
n = read(sockfd, buffer, 256);
printf("%s\n", buffer);
n = read(sockfd, buffer, 256);
printf("%s\n", buffer);
n = read(sockfd, buffer, 256);
printf("%s\n", buffer);
}
```

a2, a3, a4, a5, and a6 are strings.  The first time it runs it prints everything properly.  The second time, it prints out nothing, just a bunch of blank lines.  When I tested to find out what buffer was, I got that its "  ".  Do you know what the problem is or how I can fix it?

Comment: Try printing out the value of `n` after each `write` call, and the value of `n` after each call to `read`. If `n` is every less than zero, print the value of `errno`.

Comment: Your code ignores the return value from `read`, so it has no idea how many bytes it received. You also can't treat arbitrary bytes received over the network as a C-style string.

Comment: It says n is 256 after every call...

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to pinpoint the problem since you're not showing us the loop.

However, one thing that jumps out is that you seem to be expecting that every call to `write()` would match up with a call to `read()`. This is not how TCP works: packets get fragments, you could get partial reads etc. In other words, TCP is a [*stream* protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017633/difference-between-message-oriented-protocols-and-stream-oriented-protocols) and not a *message-oriented* one.

In particular, you should be prepared to deal with the situation whereby `read()` returns fewer than 256 bytes. That can happen to any of your `read()` calls at any time.

Also, since you're treating the 256-byte chunks as C strings, it would be prudent for the server to append its own NUL terminator instead of relying on the client to supply one.

Comment: The code is over 400 lines long.  Basically the while loop is while(l > 0) { printout(); a bunch of other stuff} in both the client and the server.  l is decreased every turn.  How do I get read/write to match up?

Comment: Since read and write aren't guaranteed to read/write the specified number of bytes, I would recommend writing wrappers for read and write that keep calling them until the specified number of bytes have been read/written.  There are other approaches, but without seeing the rest of your code, it's hard to recommend other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

'll bet your server's call to `bind()` failed on the second run.  And so the client's call to `connect()`.  Got error handling for those?

**EDIT**

Especially when doing simple TCP examples, it's not uncommon for the first run of your server to "hold on" to a port for a while after the server dies.  When you run the server a second time, `bind()` will fail, and so your server process won't be able to `listen()` or `accept()` new connections. Explaining the details is the topic of another question.

Since your server isn't actually there, `connect()` will fail on your client, leaving you with an unconnected socket.  And all subsequent reads from that socket will fail immediately, leaving `buffer` containing all 0s. This would be a possible explanation of the behavior you're seeing.

Can you rule this explanation out?  Are you checking that `bind()` and `connect()` always return 0?

Comment: The calls to bind and connect are in the main, so they only happen once.  Is that wrong?

Comment: @BM: Added some elaboration to my answer.