# Receiver loses the same last bytes of file lost sent via TCP socket in python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I send a .txt file(about 87 kbyte size) from a client to a server over TCP with the following code(python):

**Client:**

```
                        f = open(filename, 'r')
                        while 1:
                            data = f.read(1024)
                            if not data:
                                data='*Endoffile*!'
                                con.send('%1024s' %data)
                                f.close()
                                break
                            else:
                                con.send('%1024s' %data)
```

**Server:**

```
f = open(filename,'w')
while 1:
    data = c.recv(1045)
    if data=='%1024s' %'*Endoffile*!':    
        f.close()
        break
    else:
        f.write(data)
```

The problem is that the file received is always cut at the same point(it stops always at the same word when i open it), about 1,6 kbyte smaller than the size of the complete file.
Does anyone have a suggestion of what to do?

Comment: What exactly is missing? Instead of reading and writing files, generate a pattern on the sender side and verify the pattern on the receiver side. Also, what Python version are you using?

Comment: Where did the `1045` come from?

Comment: Python is last version of 2.7.x

Comment: 1045 is the size in bytes for 1024 characters in python

Comment: The last words of the .txt file are missing.

Comment: I use fixed size data to send and the string '*Endoffile*!' to recognize that there is no data to receive anymore.

Comment: "1045 is the size in bytes for 1024 characters in python" - that's wrong, the size depends on the actual characters and the used encoding. Again, write a byte-pattern and verify it on the other side to rule out failure to read or write a file (divide and conquer strategy). Also, unless you have to implement an existing protocol for file transfer, I would suggest that you use e.g. zeromq, which takes away a lot of the low-level networking complexity.

Answer (score 2):

***Solved*** by these changes in the **server** side code:

```
        while 1:
          f = open(filename,'wb')

          data=c.recv(1024)

          while ('*Endoffile*!' in data) == False:
            f.write(data)
            data=c.recv(1024)

          print data
          data=data.replace('*Endoffile*!', '')
          f.write(data)
          f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the end-of-file check is broken, so the server never breaks out of the loop. The file never gets closed and recently-written data does not get flushed to disk, resulting in a truncated file.

The reason the EOF check is broken is that TCP is a stream-oriented protocol and does not preserve message boundaries. In other words, a single `recv()` does not map to a single `send()`.

Your code, on the other hand, expects the `'%1024s' %'*Endoffile*!'` to be received in one complete `recv()`.

For further discussion, see [Difference between message-oriented protocols and stream-oriented protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017633/difference-between-message-oriented-protocols-and-stream-oriented-protocols)

Comment: I replaced:

data = c.recv(1045) 

with: 

buff=''
while len(buff) < 1045:
    buff += c.recv( 1045 - len(buff) )
data = buff
                    
It happens exactly the same